# P-Value for Fst Analysis using Microsatellite Data

Tags: r, package, genetics, population

How to find the P-Value for Fst result of Microsatellite data using R/ or any software?
my data is in genepop format.

I have tried STAMPP package in R, but seems it is only for SNP data.
Also tried DiveRsity, but didnt work